# Regex match with delimiter, not reusing the main element

Tags: regex, xsd

I would like to write a regex match phrase which contains a delimiter `,`.
These lines should match the regex:

- 1
- 1,4
- 5,7,3

This is the regex

```
[1-9](,[1-9])*
```

Is there a way to write it without repeating the main element `[1-9]` ?
Some way to say `,` is valid only from the second occurrence ?

Comment: Is it Java? What is the programming language/regex library?

Comment: Unfortunately it's "pure" regex. I can't use a variable.

Comment: It's a .yang file (RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-netmod-rfc6020bis-12#ref-XSD-TYPES), which use regex https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/

Comment: Ok, you cannot write it otherwise there. `[1-9](,[1-9])*` is OK as is. XSD regex does not support neither recursion, nor lookaheads.